# SQL: Query complete hierarchy based on a primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table like below

```
folderid    name    parent
==========================
1           one     null
2           two     1
3           three   2
4           four    3
5           five    4
6           six     5
```

Is there a way to retrieve the complete list of records when given a folderid. For example if 1 is passed it should return the complete hierarchy till the leaf that is 6. If 6 is passed it should return the complete hierarchy till the root that is 1. If 4 is passed it should return the complete hierarchy from root to the leaf that is from 1 to 6.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select folderid
      from t
      where folderid = 1
      union all
      select t.folderid
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.folderid = t.parent
     )
select *
from cte
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

If you want additional columns, you can either include them in the recursive CTE or you can join them in the outer query.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3c27fbab9615226d26c9724eac8ac4c3) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

If you want to walk up and down the tree, I would recommend two CTEs:

```
with cte_c as (
      select folderid, 1 as lev
      from t
      where folderid = 4
      union all
      select t.folderid, lev + 1
      from cte_c join
           t
           on cte_c.folderid = t.parent
     ),
     cte_p as (
      select parent, 1 as lev
      from t
      where folderid = 4
      union all
      select t.parent as folderid, lev + 1
      from cte_p join
           t
           on cte_p.parent = t.folderid
      where t.parent is not null
     )
select folderid
from cte_c
union all
select parent
from cte_p
where parent is not null
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=588d10c33d2a14fd2d8a130544c38975) is a db<>fiddle for this version.

Comment: When i run this query I get "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion" error

Comment: that means you got a loop in your hierarchy path, ie folder 1-> folder 2 -> folder 3 -> folder 1

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya . . . I fixed the answer.  There was a typo.

Comment: This gives me the children of a particular parent folder, but not the parents of the parent folder.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya . . . I missed that part of the question and updated the answer.